# Is there a way to figure out what's the current affecting speed in a timespace?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, timespace

Timespace problem: You make a big hierarchy of views, and give every layer a different speed value. Now all the Timespaces are messed up. At the bottom of the hierarchy you don't know what kind of time distortion you have. -10%? -90%? +50%?

UIKit somehow has to calculate the speed in the hierarchy when animating. So I wonder if there's a method to grab this calculated speed value?

Sure, I could try to walk up through the hierarchy and multiplicate all the speed's that are around. But maybe there's an easier way.